# Datatables.net Razor Page taking very long to load with larger data sets

Tags: c#, datatables, razor-pages, .net-5

I have a page that is fully functional, however, I wanted to use the datatables.net setup for the searchability and sorting functionality...and it's taking a rather long time to load once you crack a few hundred records.  10,000 records took upwards of 3 minutes for the page to load and be fully functional.  Is there a way to speed this up?  I got Pagination to work, but the search box that comes with it only searches the records in that page/recordset.   Is there a way to get this to load faster (IE: for it to **not** render every record before letting it be sortable), or do I need to use a different approach?

Here's the page:

```
@page
@model NBG_Central.Pages.DataCentral.ManageItemsModel

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
        <script language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<h1>Manage Products</h1>
<div>
    <form method="post">
        <button asp-page="AddItem" class="btn btn-primary">Add Item</button>

        @if (Model.products.Count() > 0)
        {

            <table id="ProdTable" class="table table-striped border">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="table-secondary">
                        <th>
                            <label>ProdID</label>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <label>Product Description</label>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <label>Active</label>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <label>Sales Category</label>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <label>Prod Category</label>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <label>Genus</label>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <label>Variety</label>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <label>Color</label>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <label>Product Code</label>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <label>PPE Item #</label>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <label>NBG SKU</label>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <label>NBG UPC</label>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <label>GP Code</label>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var prod in Model.products)
                    {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => prod.ProductID)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => prod.ProductDesc)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => prod.Active)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => prod.ProductCategory)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => prod.ProductionCategory)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => prod.Genus)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => prod.Variety)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => prod.Color)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => prod.ProductCode)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => prod.PPEItemNumber)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => prod.NBGSKU)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => prod.NBGUPC)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => prod.GPCode)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button asp-page-handler="Delete" asp-route-id="@prod.ProductID" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure')" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a asp-page="EditItem" asp-route-id="@prod.ProductID" class="btn btn-success btn-sm text-white">Edit</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
        else
        {
            <p>No Records Available</p>
        }
    </form>
</div>

@section Scripts{

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ProdTable').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Trying to handle pagination with the code-behind like this, and gets the data to load nearly instantly.  But, it results in me only searching what's in that page:

```
    public IEnumerable<Products> Items { get; set; }
    public Pager pager { get; set; }
    public SelectList TotalItemsList { get; set; }
    public int TotalItems { get; set; }
    public SelectList PageSizeList { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public SelectList MaxPagesList { get; set; }
    public int MaxPages { get; set; }
    public void OnGet(int p = 1)
    {
        TotalItemsList = new SelectList(new[] { 10, 150, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000, 1000000 });
        TotalItems = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("TotalItems") ?? 150;
        PageSizeList = new SelectList(new[] { 1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000 });
        PageSize = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("PageSize") ?? 10;
        MaxPagesList = new SelectList(new[] { 1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500 });
        MaxPages = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("MaxPages") ?? 10;
        var products = _dataCentralDAL.GetAllProducts();
        pager = new Pager(products.Count(), p, PageSize, MaxPages);
        Items = products.Skip((pager.CurrentPage - 1) * pager.PageSize).Take(pager.PageSize);
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost(int totalItems, int pageSize, int maxPages)
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("TotalItems", totalItems);
        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("PageSize", pageSize);
        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("MaxPages", maxPages);
        return Redirect("/Test/Pagination/");
    }
```

And, using this approach, the dataset makes it all the way through to be able to show it with Console.Log()... but it won't actually tie to the table:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script>
/////////
function convertToDataSet(responseJSON) {
    /*console.log(responseJSON);*/
    var returnList = [];
    var returnitem = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < responseJSON.length; i++) {
        //console.log(responseJSON[i]);
        returnitem = [];
        returnitem.push(responseJSON[i].productID);
        returnitem.push(responseJSON[i].productDesc);
        returnitem.push(responseJSON[i].active);
        returnitem.push(responseJSON[i].productCategory);
        returnitem.push(responseJSON[i].productionCategory);
        returnitem.push(responseJSON[i].productCode);
        returnitem.push(responseJSON[i].ppeItemNumber);
        returnitem.push(responseJSON[i].nbgsku);
        returnitem.push(responseJSON[i].nbgupc);
        returnitem.push(responseJSON[i].gpCode);
        returnitem.push(responseJSON[i].genus);
        returnitem.push(responseJSON[i].variety);
        returnitem.push(responseJSON[i].color);
        returnList.push(returnitem);
    }
    //console.log(returnList);
    return returnList;
}

function getTable() {
    return fetch('/Test/Pagination?Handler=Display',
        {
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
            }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.text();
            } else {
                throw Error('Response Not OK');
            }
        })
        .then(function (text) {
            try {
                return JSON.parse(text);
            } catch (err) {
                throw Error('Method Not Found');
            }
        })
        .then(function (responseJSON) {                
            var dataSet = convertToDataSet(responseJSON); 
            console.log(dataSet);
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#example').DataTable({
                    "data": dataSet,
                    "processing": true, // for show progress bar
                    "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
                    "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
                    
                    columns: [
                        { title: "ProductID" },
                        { title: "ProductDesc" },
                        { title: "Active" },
                        { title: "ProductCategory" },
                        { title: "ProductionCategory" },
                        { title: "ProductCode" },
                        { title: "PPEItemNumber" },
                        { title: "NBGSKU" },
                        { title: "NBGUPC" },
                        { title: "GPCode" },
                        { title: "Genus" },
                        { title: "Variety" },
                        { title: "Color" },
                        
                        {
                            data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                                return '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="/InvoiceDelete?id=' + row[0] + '">Delete</a>';
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "render": function (data, type, full, meta) { return '<a class="btn btn-info" href="/InvoiceEdit?id=' + full[0] + '">Edit</a>'; }
                        },
                        {
                            "render": function (data, type, full, meta) { return '<a class="btn btn-warning" href="/Index">Main Page</a>'; }
                        },
                    ]
                    
                });                    
            });
        })
}
getTable();
</script>
<table id="example" class="table table-striped border" style="width:100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ProductID</th>
        <th>ProductDesc</th>
        <th>Active</th>
        <th>ProductCategory</th>
        <th>ProductionCategory</th>
        <th>ProductCode</th>
        <th>PPEItemNumber</th>
        <th>NBGSKU</th>
        <th>NBGUPC</th>
        <th>GPCode</th>
        <th>Genus</th>
        <th>Variety</th>
        <th>Color</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the serverSide option to true in order your paging and search work properly and in server side:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ProdTable').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Is there code on the back end that needs to be done?  This change didn't help with the loading of it.  It's still trying to render all of the rows before the front-end paging kicks in.

Comment: https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/jquery-datatable-in-aspnet-core/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I wasn't able to get it working with Razor pages, however I did get it working with Blazor.  With about 4,000 records, this page loads in about 1-2 seconds and has the full datatables.net functionality.

My _host file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Blazor</title>
    <base href="~/" />
    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute"
              crossorigin="anonymous"
              integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" />
    </environment>
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <app>@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))</app>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And, the FetchData.razor file:

```
@using BlazorDataTables.Data
@using BlazorDataTables.Objects

@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime


@if (product is null)
{
    <p>Loading...</p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr class="table-secondary">
                <th>
                    <label>ProdID</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>Product Description</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>Active</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>Sales Category</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>Prod Category</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>Genus</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>Variety</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>Color</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>Product Code</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>PPE Item #</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>NBG SKU</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>NBG UPC</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>GP Code</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                </th>
                <th>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var prod in product)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @prod.ProductID
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @prod.ProductDesc
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @prod.Active
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @prod.ProductCategory
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @prod.ProductionCategory
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @prod.Genus
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @prod.Variety
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @prod.Color
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @prod.ProductCode
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @prod.PPEItemNumber
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @prod.NBGSKU
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @prod.NBGUPC
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @prod.GPCode
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="ShowHide(" test")">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @*<a href="@($"Admin/EditAdministrator/{administrator.Id}")" class="btn btn-primary table-btn">
                                Edit
                            </a>*@
                        @*<a class="btn btn-success btn-sm text-white">Edit</a>*@
                    </td>
                </tr>

            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
@code {
    private Product[] product;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        product = ForecastService.GetInventories();
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            var jQuery = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("$", "table");
            await jQuery.InvokeVoidAsync("DataTable");
        }
    }
}
```